# How can I access DOM in AngularDart?

Tags: javascript, angular, polymer, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to port some JavaScript Polymer elements to AngularDart.

I need to be able to do the equivalent of `this.$.contentContainer.getBoundingClientRect();` (for those who aren't familiar with Polymer that is basically `component.getElementById("contentContainer").getBoundingClientRect()`).

I also need to be able to access the host element to do things such as `window.getComputedStyle(this).direction` where `this` is the host element.

How would things like this usually be done in AngularDart?

Answer (score 3):

You can inject an object called `ElementRef`:

```
import 'dart:html';

class Comp {
  final ElementRef _elementRef;

  Comp(this._elementRef) {
    final element = _elementRef.nativeElement as Element;
    element.getComputedStyle(); // ...
  }
}
```

In AngularDart 4.x, we'll allow you to inject `Element` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can get a reference to a specific element using `@ViewChild()`

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '''
<div #contentContainer></div>
'''
)
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('contentContainer') HtmlElement cc;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    cc....
  }
}
```

See also [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681) (which applies to Dart with minor changes like types on the right and optional parameters in `{}`)

Comment: Does this allow you to get the host element too?

Comment: If you want the host element, use the method @matanlurey showed